# Double Mass Curve

Tags: r, error-handling, trend

I am trying to check for trends in rainfall data from various monitoring stations and I want to use the Double Mass Curve function, but when I try to install the dmcurve package, I get the following error:

> package ‘dmcurve’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2).

Comment: ``dmcurve`` is a function within a library called ``lfstat``. Try ``install.packages("lfstat")``.

Comment: It is now showing the following error: Error in library(dmcurve) : there is no package called ‘dmcurve’

Comment: ``library(lfstat)`` then you can use the **function** ``dmcurve``

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a duplicate but the commenting process doesn't seem to be "working". So here is a console screenscrape illustrating the need for setting dependencies=TRUE and to execute a `library` call to load the package:

```
> install.packages("lfstat", dependencies=TRUE)
also installing the dependency ‘lmomRFA’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/lmomRFA_3.3.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 435665 bytes (425 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 425 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/el-capitan/contrib/3.6/lfstat_0.9.4.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 855964 bytes (835 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 835 KB


The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/68/vh2f8kzn09j8954r6q9100yh0000gn/T//RtmpvvgGGI/downloaded_packages
> ?dmcurve
No documentation for ‘dmcurve’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??dmcurve’
#  The package was installed but not loaded
> library(lfstat)
Loading required package: xts
Loading required package: zoo

Attaching package: ‘zoo’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    as.Date, as.Date.numeric

Loading required package: lmom
Loading required package: lattice
> ?dmcurve    # brings up help page
```

You see that my library of packages did not have pkg:lmomRFA but it was installed because of the dependencies parameter set to TRUE. You can also execute:

```
packageDescription("lfstat")
# which prints the package's DESCRIPTION file

Package: lfstat
Type: Package
Title: Calculation of Low Flow Statistics for Daily Stream Flow Data
Version: 0.9.4
### snipped several lines ###
Depends: R (>= 2.10), xts, lmom, lattice
Imports: lmomRFA, dygraphs, zoo, latticeExtra, plyr
```

So apparently I already had most of the requirements installed. Not also that a package (pkg:zoo) got automatically loaded that were not in the `Depends:` list. It is a second level dependency that gets loaded by the 'xts' package. So you might have gotten an error on loading if that were not already in you library path.